# Select the last column value for unique ID in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on feature engineering for Churn prediction. This is dataset which contains historic data about Customer.

```
        ID Cus  Date        PLZ
    0   026     201707      366
    1   026     201708      366
    2   026     201709      366
    3   026     201710      344
    4   026     201711      344
    ...
    95  030     201712      335
    96  030     201801      335
    97  030     201802      335
    98  030     201803      333
    99  030     201804      333
```

I want to create new dataframe which contains for unique ID last value for PLZ

```
        ID Cus  Date        PLZ
    1   026     201711      344
    ...
    33  030     201804      333
```

Comment: Use `df = df.drop_duplicates('ID Cus', keep='last')`

Comment: That's rights. It was easy. Thanks